# VLC media player upgrade error: Unable to open file for writing

Tags: windows, installation, vlc-media-player

When attempting to upgrade my VLC Player to the latest version, I received the error message:

> Cannot open file for writing: libvlc.dll

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure no program is currently using that file. In my case, I had **OBS Studio** running, which interfered with the upgrade process. You can also download [process explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) (By Microsoft), and use that to find out what process has `libvlc.dll` locked:

> [image]

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your system files within windows is corrupted. Try to use these commands in Command Prompt. 
To run a system file check (SFC)
Go to start>Type CMD

Right-click and Run as Administrator

(called an elevated command prompt)

If you want to verify and repair the OS type sfc /scannow (note the space between sfc and "/").

If you just want to check (verify only) the OS type sfc /verifyonly (no changes will be made using verify only).
Dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
If that does not work. 
I say remove the VLC media player and then reinstall it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to shut down all running VLC instances and any other applications using LibVLC.

On Windows, you have to use task manager for that.

open task manager by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Esc`.